# count the no. of employee in each department and fill the counting in respecting experience column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables employee and department,Employee table schema(Eid,Ename,DOJ,Sal,Dept ID) and Department schema(Dept id,Dname).So what i want  in output is count the no. of employee by each department and according to experience.

Output:

```
dept    |0-5yrs|5-10yrs|10-15yrs
HR      |  4   |    9  |  0       
Account |  2   |    3  |  1
```

what I mean by the output is 4 employees in HR department have less than 5 years of experience and 9 people have more than 5 and less than 10 years of experience and 0 have 10-15 years of experience

Comment: Please show what you've tried. Thanks.

Comment: Here you find something on how to build a [mcve]; also, is it for Oracle or Sql-server?

Comment: Atleast provide the required output  in understandable format.

Comment: What does the DOJ field in the EMPLOYEE table contain? I'm guessing it's a date, but what does DOJ mean?

Comment: DOJ means Date of joining.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pivot table in Microsoft SQL, like this:

```
select  p.DName, p.Under5, p.From5To10, p.MoreThan10
from    (
    select  d.DName, case when datediff(day, e.DOJ, getdate()) / 365 < 5 then 'Under5' when datediff(day, e.DOJ, getdate()) / 365 > 10 then 'MoreThan10' else 'From5To10' end as ExperienceBucket
    from    Employee    e
    join    Department  d on e.[Dept Id] = d.[Dept Id]
        ) as s
pivot   (
    count(ExperienceBucket)
    for ExperienceBucket in (Under5, From5To10, MoreThan10)
        ) as p
```

Comment: If you want to be accurate, you can't use datediff in age (or similar) calculation, because it only tells you how many times the year has changed.